# How can I line-break in a word-sensitive way in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a css property that puts words on the bottom line instead of splitting them nonsense.
I applied break-word but it didn't work

```
<li class="direction-step"><strong>Ekmeğin alt kısmına süzme peyniri sürüyoruz.</strong></li>

Ekmeğin alt kısmına süzme peyniri sürüyoruz.
```

I want this;
"Ekmeğin alt kısmına süzme peyniri\n
sürüyoruz."

Not this;
"Ekmeğin alt kısmına süzme peyniri sürü(\n)
yoruz."

That is, instead of dividing words from meaningless places or syllables, I want them to divide after the words are finished and go to the bottom line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The default `word-wrap` wraps words like you want them to. There must be something else on your page causing this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because you are using non breaking spaces: `<strong>Ardından&nbsp;sırasıyla&nbsp;domatesleri,&nbsp;salatalıkları&nbsp;ve&nbsp;marulu&nbsp;koyuyoruz.</strong>`

Word press must have added them, if you can find a way for it to use normal spaces then it will fix the problem.

Comment: do you have an opinion on this? so i don't know why you do that

Comment: @theoyuncu8 html can contain something called a non breaking space (&nbsp; in above strong tag). They prevent word wrapping. I'm not sure why WordPress added them since I don't use it but the spaces in your editor will look just like a normal space. Perhaps if you try deleting a space then adding it back in it will remain as a normal space.

Comment: do you have any suggestions

Comment: @theoyuncu8 did you try deleting the spaces then adding them back in? I dont know anything about wordpress so you may have to re-ask the question as something like "why is wordpress converting spaces into non breaking spaces".

Comment: Ok. thank you, when I delete it, it automatically re-adds it, also there is no '&nbsp' there, it adds itself.. I guess it may be related to the wordpress theme, I don't know